# Отладка программ GDB

Tags: gdb, отладка

Всем привет!

Изучаю работу с отладчиком gdb.

Написал "Hello World" на C++

Скомпилировал `C:\Dev-Cpp\source>gcc hello_world.cpp`

Запускаю отладчик `C:\Dev-Cpp\source>gdb -q a.exe`

Выходит ошибка

`C:\Dev-Cpp\source>gdb -q a.exe
c:/cygmnt/prj/pkg/src/gdb/mingw32/gdb/dwarf2read.c:985: gdb-internal-error: read
_comp_unit_head: dwarf from non elf file
An internal GDB error was detected.  This may make further
debugging unreliable.  Quit this debugging session? (y or n)`

Comment: А ключ -g при трансляции не нужен?

Comment: Это какие-то видовские ошибки с gdb. 

Ключ трансляции -g нужен только для получения отладочной информации в "человеческом" виде, на работоспособность нормального gdb (в \*nix) он не влияет. 

Хотя, без -g, уж изучить-то работу с отладчиком точно не получится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установил MinGW версии 4.7.1 все заработало.